# lifetime of automatic storage that enters a nested scope

Tags: c++

Say there is an object with automatic storage duration, and that object is copy-initialized from within a nested scope, like a loop body. Is the lifetime of the values created from within the nested scope extended into the containing scope?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Thing {
public:
    int data;
    Thing(int data) : data(data) { cout << "making a thing" << endl; }
    ~Thing() { cout << "destroying a thing" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    Thing t = Thing(-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        t = Thing(i); // this is both created AND destroyed from within this scope...?
    }
    cout << t.data << endl; // undefined behavior?
}
```

Right now, accessing `t.data` at the end works, but I see that the destructor for each `Thing` is invoked once per loop iteration, so I might just be getting lucky?

This looks relevant (but I am not a lawyer so it's tough to decipher): [some 2011 c++ standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4)
specifically:

> 6. For such an object [with automatic storage duration] that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way...

So if my code snippet is undefined behavior - for a loop body to change a local variable, that local variable should be manually heap allocated and later manually released, or...?

Comment: `t` *always* refers to the same `Thing`. The expression `t = Thing(i);` does not change *which* `Thing` the `t` object refers to. It simply makes a temporary new `Thing`, copies that value to the `Thing` named `t` and then destroys the temporary `Thing`. This is value semantics and can surprise developers with background in other languages like C# and Java.

Comment: Don't read the standard for your typical problems, it really is extremely difficult (evidently). cppreference is the best default choice of reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is perfectly legal, defined behavior.

Your mistake is in thinking that the lifetime of the `Thing` created inside the block matters. It doesn't. After the copy, the copy-assigned `t` hasn't changed what it *is*; it's still the same `t` created outside the block, it just had its values updated. Its lifetime is entirely unaffected. In the context of your quote, the "block with which it[`t`] is associated" is the top-level function scope (where it was declared), not the block in which it was copy-assigned.

The `Thing` created inside the block does expire each time, but that's fine; it was copied from, then never used again.

Comment: So obvious in retrospect. I printed the addresses of everything (especially during copy init) and what you say is legit. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no undefined behavior here:

```
#include<iostream>

class Thing {
public:
    int data;
    Thing(int data) : data(data) { std::cout << "making a thing" << data << std::endl; }
    ~Thing() { std::cout << "destroying a thing" << data << std::endl; }

    Thing& operator=(const Thing &t) { data = t.data; std::cout << "operator=" << std::endl; return *this; }
};
int main() {
    Thing t = Thing(-1); // create object t
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        t = Thing(i);
        // 1. create an object Thing(i)
        // 2. use operator= to copy that object into the object t
        // 3. Thing(i) object gets destroyed at the end of scope
    }
    // object t is still valid, but it was modified in the loop with operator=
    cout << t.data << endl; // no undefined behavior here
}
```

You can add copy-assignment operator (`operator=`) member function into the Thing class to check this. In your case this operator was implicitly added by the compiler, according to the rules in the standard:

> If no user-defined copy assignment operators are provided for a class
> type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare one
> as an inline public member of the class. This implicitly-declared copy
> assignment operator has the form T& T::operator=(const T&) if all of
> the following is true:
>
> 1. each direct base B of T has a copy assignment operator whose
>    parameters are B or const B& or const volatile B&
> 2. each non-static data
>    member M of T of class type or array of class type has a copy
>    assignment operator whose parameters are M or const M& or const
>    volatile M&

Comment: Less intrusive and more accurate demo: https://godbolt.org/z/6esqT6 (your modification changes behavior of class a bit: disables move assignment).

Comment: Yes, totally agree, it also covers move assignments.